# SSH “Could not open input file: bin/magento” Magento2

Tags: magento2, ssh

I'm trying to reindexing my Magento 2 
I have done these steps in putty

[image]

can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?
I'm new in using SSH that's why

thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write:

```
cd public_html/magedemo instead of cd /public_html/magedemo
```

You will then be in the root directory of your installation and bin/magento commands will hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether you are running the commands from the right place or not, you can do the following:

> **Step 1:** Create/upload a file (**say:** info.php) and put the following content in the file:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

and open the following URL in the browser:

```
http://[websiteurl]/info.php
```

> **Step 2:** Note down the path mentioned under the heading **`document_root`**.

> **Step 3:** Run the following command to change the directory:

```
cd [the-path-noted-in-step-2-as-document_root]
```

> **Step 4:** Now try to run any Magento 2 command from this location. If still, you are getting the same error, please comment or update the question.